# TableName of the result query

Tags: php, mysql, tablename

When the result of a query exists, I want to know the name of the row(s) that have the correct results:

```
$query = "SELECT Id FROM Programacao WHERE ID = 1";
$curDate = date("Y-m-d H").':00:00';
$query = "SELECT Id 
    FROM Programacao 
    WHERE Data1 = '$curDate'
       OR Data2 = '$curDate'
       OR Data3 = '$curDate'"
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){}
```

simply talking its `if(Data1 == curDate)return Data1; if(Data2 == curDate)return Data2`....

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why do you need this information? You _know the table name when you write the query_, so why ask the database for something you already know, or are you confusing "tables" with "rows"?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Aren't you querying a single table in that statement?

Comment: Your table name is Programacao.  Also that query limits the result set to either being empty or returning "1".  Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Well it would be `Programacao` from your query. But if you needed it dynamically you could try functions like [`mysql_table_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php) or [`mysql_field_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php).

Answer (score 0):

A select statement does **not** go into a table.
It goes into a resultset.
Resultsets do not have names, they just are.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Result_set

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this? (either with `UNION` or `UNION ALL`):

```
$query = "
  SELECT Id
       , 'Data1' AS name 
  FROM Programacao 
  WHERE Data1 = '$curDate'
UNION 
  SELECT Id
       , 'Data2' 
  FROM Programacao 
  WHERE Data2 = '$curDate'
UNION
  SELECT Id
       , 'Data3' 
  FROM Programacao 
  WHERE Data3 = '$curDate'
         " ;
```